# Error showing throwing an instance of std::out_of_range

Tags: c++, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I am solving leetcode question : Cousins in Binary Tree

Link for problem statement: https://leetcode.com/problems/cousins-in-binary-tree/

**Logic**:

Implementing bfs from root node and  storing the distance of each child node from the root node in a "**dis**" vector and storing each node's parent node in a vector "**pred**" .

If parent node is not same and distance of x and y in function **isCousin** is same , then return true else false.

**MY CODE:**

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> dis={0};
    vector<int> pred={-1};
    // vector<bool> vis={false};
    struct TreeNode *temproot,*curr;

    void bfs(TreeNode *root){

        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        int initDis=0;

        q.push(root);
        // vis.push_back(true);
        dis.push_back(0);
        pred.push_back(-1);

        while(!q.empty()){

            curr=q.front();
            q.pop();
            initDis += 1;

            if(curr->left != NULL){
                pred.push_back(curr->val);
                temproot=curr->left;
                // vis.push_back(true);
                dis.push_back(initDis);
                q.push(temproot);
            }
            else continue;

                if(curr->right != NULL){
                pred.push_back(curr->val);
                temproot=curr->right;
                // vis.push_back(true);
                dis.push_back(initDis);
                q.push(temproot);
            }
            else continue;


        }
    }

    bool isCousins(TreeNode* root, int x, int y) {
        if(root==NULL) return false;

        bfs(root);

        if(pred.at(x-1) == pred.at(y-1)) return false;

        else
            if(dis.at(x-1) == dis.at(y-1)) return true;
            else return false;



    }
};
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Runtime Error Message:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Last executed input:
[1,2,3,null,4,null,5]
5
4
```

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the exception. Where in your code is it thrown? What are the values of all involved variables at that point? What are the sizes of all involved vectors or arrays? What is the index you might use to access them?

Comment: Can you suggest  a debugger ?

Comment: If you use an IDE is usually comes with one. For Linux systems use `gdb` in a terminal. For macOS without Xcode also use `gdb` or `lldb`.